# Creating Python package alias TypeError: expected string or buffer error

Tags: python, package, alias

I am trying to make a python package alias, by writing a small script in my site-packages. Here I am trying to use json by naming it as ujson.

```
#ujson.py
import json

def dumps(*args, **kwargs):
    return json.dumps(args, kwargs)

def loads(*args, **kwargs):
    return json.loads(args, kwargs)


#test.py
import ujson
d = {'a': 'b'}
du = ujson.dumps(d)
lo = ujson.loads(du)
```

Strangely, its working for `dumps` but for `loads` its giving `TypeError: expected string or buffer`

Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to propagate the arguments properly.

```
return json.dumps(*args, **kwargs)
```

But really...

```
dumps = json.dumps
loads = json.loads
```

Answer (score 1):

You need pass arguments with stars

```
def dumps(*args, **kwargs):
    # args - tuple
    # kwargs - dict
    return json.dumps(*args, **kwargs)
```